# Is it better to upload a file to an s3 bucket on the front end or backend?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, google-cloud-functions, frontend, backend

I am creating a web app where there is an option for authenticated users to upload pictures. I am confused as to whether its better to do it on the front end or backend. I have already implemented it on the front end but I had to include my "accessKeyId" and "secretKey". I don't know if this compromises my security. I am using cloud functions for my back end. If anyone can help me with best practices in relation to this I will be very grateful.

Comment: So you shouldn't be uploading straight from front end to S3, cos as you mentioned your requests will include your secret AWS keys. So anyone can look in their browser's network tab and see your private keys. Best is for the user to upload the file to a cloud function, and then in that cloud function you can upload it to S3. Since the public doesn't have access to your cloud function code and can't see those requests, they won't be able to see your keys. Obviously gotta make sure that you make the cloud function only accept requests from authenticated users

Answer (score 12):

You can generate pre-signed urls from your backend, then your frontend can upload files safely directly into S3 without exposing your credentials.

Take a look into the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html).

Also, [this](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/uploading-files-directly-to-s3-using-pre-signed-post-request) article points out some of the advantages of that strategy:

1. You can still allow only authenticated users to get access to presigned urls
2. You can set expiration time for the generated presigned urls
3. You save bandwidth, memory processing and upload time by avoiding your files to pass through your backend function

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to summarize the key parts into the answer here and provide the links for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked pages change. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30367179)